How to use transparency in legacy Thunderbird without destroying the title bar?
For experimental purposes I have Thunderbird v.52 x86 (pre-quantum and with legacy addons) installed on one of my computers (Windows 7 here). Now I would like some GUI elements to have a transparent background color - this is possible with CSS, whether userChrome.css or addon does not matter.
But there is an unexpected negative side effect. If I specify transparency with RGBA scheme or procentual opacity, then title bars of child windows get lost (no joke). The same goes for the about:config setting ui.use_native_colors if it is set to false:


It definitely has to do with the transparency colors. Because if I choose an normal RGB color and without opacity specifications, the color gets applied and title bar is kept available too.
My idea:

Keeping ui.use_native_colors = true and only override native colors on target elements like this one:

/* Symbol bar: Write new mail */
#msgcomposeWindow {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}

What I have tried so far:

made sure the title bar is missing entirely annd not only beyond desktop borders (by minimizing and maximizing the window by taskbar icon)
different approaches for transparency like background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);, opacity: 0.99;, color: transparent;
used transparent background image -> is not shown at all and default colors remain
set transparency to needed elements only (to avoid native colors forbidden in general)
limited to partly transparency
tried existing addons like glasser4tb@skp-software.com
tried JavaScript to temporary override native color usage
restarted computer and Thunderbird several times as well as deleted whole TB profile to verify it's not a one-time bug

Does anyone have an idea which changes to the CSS are necessary to keep both, transparency symbol bars and the title bar that works with my Thunderbird 52?
